# Excel - INDEX formula not grabbing data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Why is the formula below not grabbing the data from V:10 but instead R:8 on my Electronic Time Sheet?

```
=INDEX('Electronic Time Sheet'!$B:$V, MATCH(A5, 'Electronic Time Sheet'!C:C, FALSE)+1, 17)*'Hire and Payment Register'!E5
```

[image]

Comment: Are the number of items in the match range the same as the number in the index range?

Comment: Replace `FALSE` with `0`.  Also you know this will return the value in R8, which by your photo is nothing.

Comment: @ScottCraner instead of returning R8 how do I make it return V10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Match's third criterion are -1,0,1 not TRUE/FALSE.

> `MATCH(A5, 'Electronic Time Sheet'!C:C, 0)`

2. `17` will refer to column R in this index.  If you know your column just use that one alone

> `INDEX('Electronic Time Sheet'!$V:$V,`

3. you want the row 3 down from where the MATCH finds the match.

> `+3`

---

```
=INDEX('Electronic Time Sheet'!$V:$V, MATCH(A5, 'Electronic Time Sheet'!C:C, 0)+3)*E5
```